# Wordpress site under windows XP - appears to be many problems

Tags: css, wordpress, windows-xp

Would someone mind looking at this fairly basic (I thought) site that I've built for my father?

[www.pws-consulting.com](http://www.pws-consulting.com)

It loads up fine and works under the latest version of chrome, firefox, safari on my mac, and does the same on windows 7, even in ie. (though some of the css dies, which is acceptable).

On his windows xp machine however, the site has many problems.

1. Explorer browser.
   Upon initially accessing the website, the following error message appears "Internet Explorer encountered a problem and needs to close".
   When I hit "Don't send" for the error report, the tab for the website is recovered and it reopens.  Pics and text content look ok.
   However for every hyperlink (Services, Contact, etc), the same error message above appears.
   Eventually the browser crashes.
2. Firefox browser:
   Website opens normally but all text content is mispositioned at the bottom of each page, hyperlinks repeat, colour map does not appear, etc.
   All-in-all, a formatting mess.

I've used AdobeBrowser Lab to test the site and it appears to be finder going back to IE 7, Firefox 5.0 on windows so I'm at a lose to understand what is wrong.

Thanks in advance for any help. All the best to everyone in this new year.
Cam

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem to crash on WinXP IE 6.0 for me. Works great on IE 7+ though. No problems in Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari either. Must be an issue with your computer? Did you try another computer?

Comment: No, I've only been trying on my father's computer . . . is that possible though? One computer can screw up how it displays a simple site like this?
Thanks for your help too. Much appreciated.

Comment: It must be your browser. Try another PC.